# count query taking too much time

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to count all my table data but count query is taking too much time (2-3 minutes) against 0.2M records only. I have applied all possible ways created index against ID, used raw query as well as ORM but still same result. Simple query below:

```
Query:   Customer::select('id')->count();
```

Note: It is working fine on local and getting result in milliseconds but in AWS server it is taking time.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using two different hosts for DB and web server ?

Comment: Yes @medilies I'm using two different hosts for DB and webserver

Comment: Well that can be the time that your query is taking to do a roundtrip between the two hosts (network delay). It would be helpful if you specify what hosting services are you using and tag them (Maybe the service you are using spins up a new container to handle your request or it has a performance limitation).

Comment: I have installed apachi web server under ec2 instance and mysql database under db instance

Comment: Check the performance of your DB by directly running `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM customers` and see how long it takes. You can also `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev` and see the statistics from **Laravel**'s POV

Comment: you can also try to do [something like this](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-explain-analyze/#:~:text=EXPLAIN%20ANALYZE%20is%20a%20profiling,points%20in%20the%20execution%20plan.) to find have a better understanding of what is going on

Comment: It took 208 seconds (more than about 3.5 minutes ) by directly running the mention query.

Comment: The issue is isolated on your **DB instance** focus further debugging on it.

Comment: Also post table schema and index to see it is there your problems lie :)

Comment: As @mrhn said, make sure your indexes on the instance are up to date.  Also, what is the instance type and size?  If it's in the t2 class, remember that it operates on CPU credits, and once you exhaust those, CPU performance will be severely degraded (the underlying EBS volume also works on a similar system of credits, so you may want to check that, too).  I'd start with your CloudWatch metrics to see if you can find where it is bound, and then work to remediate any issues.

Comment: ok thanks @mrhn for info. I will get back to you on the same. :)

Answer (score 2):

As count is an aggregate function it literally takes time to count data.
Either use query builder or raw query in order to get the best performance.

```
DB::table('customers')->count('id');
```

or

```
DB::select("select count(id) from customers groupBy id")
```